# How to handle autopopulated selects (from oneToMany relation) in Symfony form?

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine

I have a ProductCategory class that has a parent and some children, properly annotated using Doctrine.

Then I have a ProductCategoryType (form class) that I use to render the html form.

Doctrine does its magic and creates a select box for parent which consists of previously added categories.

My problem: How to I prepend a default option (say '0' => 'No parent category') and how do I remove a particular category from list (ex: the currently edited category, so user can't select the very category to be its own parent)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can easily be achieved by using DataTransformers.

You can find more information in the documentation chapter [How to use Data Transformers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html).